# How to run a reusable workflow conditionally?

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, jobs

I have the following workflow in my GitHub actions:

```yaml
name: Tests e2e iOS App

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      skip:
        type: boolean
        required: true
        default: false

jobs:
  build-simu-ios-zip:
    name: Build iOS simulator zip
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-e2e-buildsimuioszip.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

I would like to run the job `build-simu-ios-zip` conditionally, I add the following:

```
jobs:
  build-simu-ios-zip:
    name: Build iOS simulator zip
+   if: ${{ inputs.skip == 'false' }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-e2e-buildsimuioszip.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

But the job automatically get skipped.

I also tried to pass an input to the reusable workflow and make it conditionally it from there, but it also skip.

How can I make a conditional reusable workflow in GitHub action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3595578319) and using `if: ${{ inputs.skip == 'false' }}` with single quotes `'` doesn't work as you are comparing a `boolean` type with a `string`.

However, I found 2 options that worked:

- `if: ${{ inputs.skip == false }}` (no quote)
- `if: ${{ ! inputs.skip }}` (as it's a boolean input, but with `!`)

*Note: I used [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester73.yml) for tests.*

Comment: It work, but I had to use `if: ${{ always() }}` on the following job otherwise both jobs are skipped.

Comment: Are the other jobs depending on this one with the condition, or from the input as well?

Comment: They conditionaly depend on this condition. If we enable demo, the other step will adapt, if we don't it will adapt.

Comment: Depending on the condition implemented in the `if` expression, it may indeed be necessary to use the `always()` to evaluate it each time, otherwise it might be skipped.

Comment: actually, we do not want `always()` we want when `inputs.skip` is `true`, to run it always, otherwise, it has to fail if the `build-simu-ios-zip` job fail. Do you have a clue ?

Comment: Did you try using the `build-simu-ios-zip` job status in the next job if expression?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, I did some attempt without `${{ always() }}` without success. with `${{ inputs.skip == true || (inputs.skip == false && contains(join(needs.skip.result, ','), 'success'))  }}`, without success